# How can I used predict_linear in promql to predict http server prometheus metrics

Tags: prometheus, promql

How can I use `predict_linear` in PromQL to predict HTTP server Prometheus metrics?

I have quantiles, counters, distribution summaries, etc.

```
predict_linear(sum(rate(http_request_latency_seconds_bucket{method="GET", status_code="200"}[5m])), 30m)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`predict_linear`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#predict_linear) takes a range vector and a scalar (seconds).

You need to convert the `sum(rate(...[5m]))` from a vector to a range. You can do this by adding a subquery e.g. `sum(rate(...[5m]))[1h:5m]`.

Finally you can apply `predict_linear(sum(rate(...[5m]))[1h:5m],120)` to calculate the regression e.g. 2 minutes (120 seconds) into the future.

You'll have to analyse the results, I don't know how best to combine `rate(..[X])` with `predict_linear(...[A:Y])` but I assume Y>X.

Comment: One more notice about use of `predict_linear`: if you use it, exact values of input metric are not preserved. If you want to preserve exact values and only use prediction where metrics are missing, use something like `my_metric or predict_linear(my_metric[5m],30)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [DazWilkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76259336/21363224):

`rate` is a bad function to linearly predict: it has rather unpredictable "jumps".

I would consider using something like `increase` instead. That way you will be predicting not the per-second approximation, but number of request over some meaningful period of time.

```
predict_linear(sum(increase(...[5m]))[1h:5m],120)
```

---

Additionally, in [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax you can left `resolution` part empty, and Prometheus will handle it (by substituting evaluation interval).

```
predict_linear(sum(increase(...[5m]))[1h:],120)
```